# django - how to separate a queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am creating a messaging app, between the users. Hope fully with the help, I came up with the business logic, I think will work. So now, I can send message and get all the messages (sent and received) for a particular user (eg. A). But I am stuck in querying or separating that messages (all the sent/received messages of A) by each user (eg. messages sent/received by A and B, messages sent/received by A and C). Below is my models.py. Please have a look and kindly help me out. Or if there's a better way out please advise me. Will be much appreciated. Thank you.

models.py

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender_set")
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="recipient")
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

# To get all the messages of A
>>> conversation = Thread.objects.filter(Q(sender=A) | Q(recipient=A))
[<Thread: A to B><Thread: C to A><Thread: B to A><Thread: A to C><Thread: A to B>]
```

How to get separate `conversation` for each user? Hope I have cleared my point. Thank you.

Comment: What you want is to get all messages between 2 specific users or all messages (sent and recieved) from 1 specific user?

Comment: I want to get separate message set of A and B, and A and C.

Comment: Did you try to handle this with 2 queries?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't follow. Could you please elaborate a little?

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you not to reinvent the wheel. I had a similar task recently and I've found it very easy to simply adopt the code from the excellent [user_messages](https://github.com/eldarion/user_messages) project. In order to adopt and understand what I was doing I needed to understand the DB model utilized, which is the following:

[image]

Basically your `User` model (whether the standard one or the one you override the standard one with) has:

- 1:N (one to many) `Message`
- 1:N (one to many) `UserThread`

A `Thread` has 1:N `UserThread`, which makes it easy to group the messages under threads, depending on which user you are displaying the thread to.

Modeling the data in this way makes the retrieval of separate conversations for each user (what you ask) trivial.

Please look into their [`models.py`](https://github.com/eldarion/user_messages/blob/master/user_messages/models.py) and related [`managers.py`](https://github.com/eldarion/user_messages/blob/master/user_messages/managers.py). You will realize the good design decisions they've made and put into the code. I had to extend it myself since it didn't cater for all my use cases. But I did really find it easy to extend.

By the way: I found `user_messages` by looking at the [django packages already available for messages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/messaging/) using the extremely helpful [djangopackages.com](http://djangopackages.com) website.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the advice. I saw the models.py, but I am still trying to grasp this. Could you please explain a little bit more...

Comment: Hi @Aamu, can you be specific about what you need explaining? If you're finding hard to understand the db model, draw a diagram of the DB on a piece of paper, and make sense out of it. It will not happen in a few seconds. Also, run and understand the unit tests for the models and managers.

Comment: From what I can understand: 1) One `Thread` has a subject and can have many Users. 2)A `User` can have many threads, with an unread and a delete attributes. And that's all. I can't understand the `Message` class, and also why are `Subject` and `Content` kept separately? Could you please kindly explain it to me and also please correct me if what I am understanding is wrong.

Comment: A `subject` is kept per `Thread`. The `content`, which is the actual message's text, is kept per `Message`. Think how FB conversations work, this is very very similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
(eg. messages sent/received by A and B, messages sent/received by A and C)
```

If i understand correctly your question; what you want is to get all messages between 2 users(sent or recieved). So based on your model design, these 2 queries gives you what you want:

```
c1 = Thread.objects.filter(sender=A, recipient=B)
c2 = Thread.objects.filter(sender=B, recipient=A)

total = list(c1) + list(c2) # this will give you all messages between A and B
```

You can create a function to handle this for multiple specific users:

```
def separate_messages(user1, user2):
    c1 = Thread.objects.filter(sender=user1, recipient=user2)
    c2 = Thread.objects.filter(sender=user2, recipient=user1)

    total = list(c1) + list(c2)
    return total

users = [B, C, D, E]
const_user = A

for user in users:
    print separate_messages(const_user, user)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. But suppose there are many messages of A and different users, how do I go about separating them?

Comment: i dont get it. above, c1 gives you messages between A and __only__ B. There are no other users.

Comment: Yes. I am sorry. Please let me elaborate a little more. Now we know that B exist, and so the above code works fine. But there can be many other messages between A and C, or A and D, or A and E,.., or A and n. And not just B. So how do I go about separating all those messages from different users? Do I have to for loop between each users, eg: `sender != A` and `recipient != A`?

Comment: If above result works fine; you can create a function takes 2 parameters: one is sender one is recipient. Then you can use that function with a for loop.

Comment: added that function. see the answer please. @Aamu